# Can I swap the rows in a DataGrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

Can I change the row index dynamically in asp.net? I have a requirement where I need to change a row in a data grid in asp.net based on the column value.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your question?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can iterate through the datagrid, take note of the field that allows the user to set the display order. Build up a collection based on that, order by the display order and then rebind the grid to it. does that sound like what you're trying to do?